# Python - Delete elements of several sublists at the same index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am developing an algorithm for the analysis of biological data for the lab I'm working in but i feel stuck at a point. The idea is to compare several experiences containing the same type of data from a single `csv` file.

I am filtering a list of lists depending on one of the values in the element in the `sublist` (which are also list of length 3), i don't know how many `sublist`s are composing my main list neither their length (thousands) but I want to delete the `i`th element in all of them. (I have a list of index)

An example may be more explicative.

Here's my list of lists of list (with known length), my "list of index"

```
mainlist=[[[a,1,1,5],[b,2,1,50],[c,3,1,5]],[[alph,1,2,5],[bet,2,2,50],[gam,3,2,5]]] 
indextodelete=[1] (where the 4rth element is > 10)
```

I try to get the following output

```
out=[[[a,1,1],[c,3,1]],[[alph,1,2],[gam,3,2]]]
```

I'm not very used to `numpy` or `pandas`.

I tried to use `pop()`, or by reversing my lists because i have a lot of elements to delete and i already have my index list. Here, `npa` is my main list and `pval` is the threshold given by the user.

```
for i,l in enumerate(npa):
    for l,k in reversed(list(enumerate(l))):
        if float(k)>float(pval):
            npa[0:len(npa)][l].pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This post isn't really clear, but to get from A -> B with this example I would run:

```
main_list = [
    [[0, 1, 1, 5], [0, 2, 1, 50], [0, 3, 1, 5]],
    [[0, 1, 2, 5], [0, 2, 2, 50], [0, 3, 2, 5]]
]
index_to_delete = 1
for sub_list in main_list:
    del sub_list[index_to_delete]
    for smallest_list in sub_list:
        smallest_list.pop()
print(main_list)
```

With output that matches what you've specified:

> [[[0, 1, 1], [0, 3, 1]], [[0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2]]]

Note: I have substituted 0 for `a`, `b`, `c`, etc since these were not provided

This may not be exactly what you were looking for, but I think it should set you on the right track at least!

Comment: Thank you for that, in fact i have a list of index of elements to delete but i realized that the data weren't as i expected so had to do a list of tuple (the 'position' of the smallest list) i also finally used numpy arrays, you may be interested or have some remarks about the code below.